# Unbtunu 18.04 shuts down instead of restarting

Tags: 18.04, ssh, shutdown, reboot

When I try to restart the system over ssh:

```
sudo reboot
```

The computer shuts down instead.

I am running Ubuntu 18.04 on a Dell Precision 5820 workstation.

Why could that be? How do I make it reboot?

Answer (score 0):

The command should be:

```
sudo shutdown –r
```

the -r switch at the end indicates that you want the machine to restart. sudo will run the command as administrator and so will require the administrator password.

Comment: Yes, I log in via ssh and then run the command `sudo reboot`, so I think your first suggestion is equivalent to what I am doing.

Comment: I've changed that then to just the one command.

Comment: That doesn't work as well. I specified the hardware because I suspect it could be a driver or hardware-specific issue. I don't know if that is possible.

Comment: when you say it doesn't work either... does it shut down (as you said in the case of sudo reboot) or apparently does nothing?

Comment: Yes it appears to be the same outcome as `reboot`.

Answer (score 0):

poweroff --reboot

halt --reboot

shutdown -r

systemctl reboot

Do all commands do the same thing?
Does it only shutdown like that when you ssh'd in?

I am no ACPI expert but I have had problems with 'only' Dells and the BIOS/UEFI that they've used(coupled with my unconventional installs) causing PCs to not shutdown or reboot in the past.

Did this just start?
Do the other options work when you're trying to shutdown?
if you did reboot -p, will it shutdown like it's supposed to?
...long shot, could "reboot" be aliased to "reboot -p"

Comment: The problem with `reboot` has always been there. It's a new server, being used by multiple people. Other users reported the same issue with the system failing to reboot, but I would chalk it up to wrong reboot commands. But I believe them now.